# Python-OGR: nested loop only loops once

Tags: python, ogr, loop

I have a polygon file `buffer_stands.shp` with 20 features and I have a line file `OSMroads.geojson` with 9 features.

I expected the script to loop through the buffers and print out for each buffer loop the the point count of each of the OSMroads. I know it doesn't sound useful, but the script is a simplification of a bigger script.

The outer loop loops all the way through. But the inner loop only loops once. What is causing that and how can I fix it?

```
import ogr

bufferfn = ogr.Open('buffer_stands.shp')
buffer_lyr = bufferfn.GetLayer()

roadfn  = ogr.Open('OSMroads.geojson')
road_lyr = roadfn.GetLayer()

for buffer_feat in buffer_lyr:
    buffer_geom = buffer_feat.GetGeometryRef()
    print 'buffer'

    for road_feat in road_lyr:
        road_geom = road_feat.GetGeometryRef()
        print road_geom.GetPointCount()
```

---

The output looks like this

```
>>> 
buffer
10
62
17
46
10
28
97
78
121
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
buffer
```

It shows the inner loop is running only once.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about your data, and what you expect the code to do (in words, at a functional level, not at a code level)? My guess is that there is only one feature in the roads GeoJSON, but since you haven't shown us the data, its difficult to say.

Comment: I added some more information. In the roads GeoJSON are nine features.

Comment: OK, I see the problem. The problem is that the roads layer has been "read to the end" already. You need to reset / re-open it, or perhaps just store it in a local list

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Reading the roads layer inside the outer loop fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ogr.Layer.ResetReading()](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#aad0f2cd7f0587584b8f382c6a913583c) method.

```
bufferfn = ogr.Open('buffer_stands.shp')
buffer_lyr = bufferfn.GetLayer()

roadfn  = ogr.Open('OSMroads.geojson')
road_lyr = roadfn.GetLayer()

for buffer_feat in buffer_lyr:
    buffer_geom = buffer_feat.GetGeometryRef()
    print 'buffer'

    for road_feat in road_lyr:
        road_geom = road_feat.GetGeometryRef()
        print road_geom.GetPointCount()

    road_lyr.ResetReading() #Read the road layer from the beginning again
```

Comment: Nice, wasn't aware of this one

Answer (score 2):

Not really understand what you want to achieve
To make it work, just move

```
roadfn  = ogr.Open('OSMroads.geojson')
road_lyr = roadfn.GetLayer() t
```

one line before `for road_feat in road_lyr:` an the loop

The point here is "think of `road_lyr` as a variable when you loop that empty itself (for memory purpose)"

You can just confirm this by doing:

```
import ogr

bufferfn = ogr.Open('buffer_stands.shp')
buffer_lyr = bufferfn.GetLayer()

for buffer_feat in buffer_lyr:
    buffer_geom = buffer_feat.GetGeometryRef()
    print 'buffer'

//second loop not working the expected way
for buffer_feat in buffer_lyr:
    buffer_geom = buffer_feat.GetGeometryRef()
    print 'buffer'
```

Although it will solve the problem, it's not really nice way to do.
You'd better take a look on [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/index.html) ( a nice wrapper on top of OGR)

Comment: Moving the `ogr.Open` and `GetLayer` part inside the outer loop fixed the problem. Thanks for pointing out Fiona. I will look into it, since opening up the datasource each loop will slow down the script quite a bit.